# Is LQR obsolete compared to non constrained MPC?

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

I have heard that LQR and MCP have common similarities. The difference is that MPC is using QP-programming and LQR using Riccati Equations. With QP-programming, constraints can be applied.

If we compare non constrained MPC and LQR, the difference is that LQR is optimal for a infinity time window and MPC is optimal for just a specific time window. I think it called time window. I hope you understand what word I want to use.

But is LQR obsolete compared to non constrained MPC? I mean, in practice, it would be better to have a basic non constrained MPC than LQR because an optimal state space model does not exist in reallity? Basic non constrained MPC uses simple least square to compute the future input signals for the system.

Are there situations there LQR is better in use than MPC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the prediction horizon and model dimensions MPC will be more or much more computationally expensive compared to LQR. This may lead to added delay or require more expensive hardware. Namely (infinite horizon) LQR just needs to compute a gain matrix beforehand and after that the computation cost online is fairly small.

It can also be noted that LQR can be used as a roll-out policy for MPC and there also exists finite horizon LQR, which has a time varying gain matrix (which can still be calculated in advance).

Comment: It could be added that the MPC optimiziation can fail if no feasible solution is found and that the LQR comes with robustness guarantees (see: Safonov  & Athans (1977) Gain and phase margin for multiloop LQG regulators) which cannot be made for the MPC.

Comment: @MrYouMath Since MPC and LQR can solve the same problem, then if MPC would fail LQR would as well. The same holds for the margins, however I do not know if one could still talk about margins in the finite horizon problem.

Comment: Are you sure that they solve the same problem? MPC is used with a moving horizon and LQR is used for infinite horizon.

Comment: If we assume that we have a fast modern computer that solve MPC on 0.001 seconds. Like a embedded Microcontroller.

Comment: @MrYouMath receding horizon is indeed different compared to (in)finite LQR. But if you choose a terminal cost in MPC based on the solution to the infinite horizon LQR then they do yield the same results. This is essentially what is meant when using LQR as roll out policy. This can also gives stability guarantees, which you do not have with no roll out policy.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson Still for certain dynamics of for example robots 0.001 seconds can still be too slow. Or 0.001 might also not be a realistic computation time when your state vector has a length of say one million which is not uncommon when using for example a model based on finite element method. The only advantage I can think of when one could use unconstrained MPC over LQR would be that it is easier to switch to constrained MPC on a later date.

Comment: Ok. I understand. When performance is important, then LQR is better. @KwinvanderVeen

Comment: @DanielMårtensson It depends, because when you also add constraints then only MPC can solve it, but when both MPC and LQR try to solve the same problem you might as well use LQR since you only once need to solve for the optimal gain.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen But insn't non constrainted MPC much better than LQR because MPC finds the good values and LQR finds the optimal values?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89972/discussion-between-kwin-van-der-veen-and-daniel-martensson).

Comment: Hi Kevin! If I have a state space model with internal delay, I don't need MPC then? Will MPC be the same as LQR if MPC is non constrainted?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson depends on how you formulate the horizon and terminal terminal cost. But it should be possible to formulate an equivalent policy and the internal delay shouldn't change this.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen But isn't LQR for infinitive horizon, but MPC is for a limit horizon? The reason why MPC excist is because the QP-solvers? Else LQR is the same as MPC in practice? I'm trying to implement a MPC or LQR controller onto a STM32 microcontroller, but the memory isn't enough for MPC. So I think I will only compute a LQR control law if there is no reason to choose non constrained MPC over LQR? The state space model I'm using is estimated from data.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson there is also [finite horizon LQR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear%E2%80%93quadratic_regulator#Finite-horizon,_discrete-time_LQR). Also MPC normally uses a receding horizon, so can be used indefinitely. If you use MPC without constraints you should effectively also get $u_k=-K\,x_k$ with $K$ a constant matrix.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Ok, now I understand. Finite horizon LQR is the same as non-constrained MPC. But which are best actually? Finite horizon or infinite horizon? I'm using the MATLAB command ´lqr(A,B,Q,R)´

Comment: @DanielMårtensson the lqr command in Matlab is infinite horizon for continuous systems (MPC is used for discrete systems so in order to compare you would have to use dlqr instead). If you are mainly concerned about memory usage and computation time I would go for infinite horizon, because then the observer gain is constant for LTI systems.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen According to MATLAB, dlqr is infinitive horizon too. https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/dlqr.html So is there any benefits of finite horizon than infinite horizon?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson it would yield a smaller cost when calculating the cost with a finite horizon, but in practice one never really knows how long exactly a system needs to be controlled. So I would say as control policy finite LQR is probably hardly used. I could maybe be useful as a way of full state reference trajectory generation.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Thanks! Good to know some practical aspects! :) I will use infinitive horizon LQR then, also with kalman filter.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Hi again. Have you seen any examples/papers where LQG is appliced with integration? If not, why?

Comment: Dear Kwin, unfortunately, I do not have enough scores to create a new tag. Do you believe creating an MPC tag would be great for MPC enthusiasts?